# EF4 CodeFirst CTP4 - Insert with existing association

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef4-code-only

If I have an entity that has an association (e.g. Book.Publisher), how do I save a new Book and associate it with an existing Publisher?

**BTW I don't want to expose FK associations (i.e. PublisherId) in my model.**

I had been using something like this:

```
var book = new Book { Title="whatever", Publisher = new Publisher { Id = 42 } };
context.Books.Add(book);
```

But this just tries to add a new publisher.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578524/1-to-1-object-relations-in-ef4-code-first/3579840#3579840) which suggested using ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState but I get an error if I try this - **The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'Blah.Publisher'.**

Comment: Can you provide more info about your implementation? I have no problem to use ObjectStateManager when using AddObject on ObjectSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pub = new Publisher { Id = 42 };
context.Publishers.Attach(pub);
var book = new Book { Title="whatever", Publisher = pub };
context.Books.Add(book);
```

Comment: Should be context.Publishers.Attach(pub) but thanks a million. The ObjectStateManager approach seemed a bit overboard.

Comment: But doesn't that require another trip to the database to load this data in?  I don't care what the data is, I just want to reference it!

Comment: Well, this is the kind of thing I'd rather find documentation on.  Testing to prove conclusively that additional database trips aren't involved would be complicated.  That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @uosɐſ: It [*is* in the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx)